# IntelliJ runs JUnit4 tests without a problem, maven test gets exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockwebserver

I´m currently having nightmares testing my Spring WebClient code.
Given the following simple method

```
 private String request(String uri, String body) {
    return webClient
            .method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .uri(uri)
            .body(Mono.just(body), String.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
}
```

and the following Unit Test:

```
 @Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:%s";
    mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
    mockWebServer.start();
    int mockWebServerPort = mockWebServer.getPort();
    baseUrl = String.format(baseUrl, mockWebServerPort);
    webClient = WebClient.create();
}



 @After
public void shutdown() throws IOException {
    mockWebServer.shutdown();
}

    @Test
public void testPost() throws InterruptedException {
    String body = "Hello";
    givenMockResponse(response -> {
        response.setResponseCode(200);
        response.setBody(body);
    });
    request(baseUrl, body);
    RecordedRequest recordedRequest = mockWebServer.takeRequest();
    checkRequest(recordedRequest);
}
```

It passes when I run the test via IntelliJ but when I´m using maven it throws the following exception:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 0ms in 'flatMap' (and no fallback has been configured)
```

The request method also runs fine when I start my Spring Boot Application and test it manually. My project uses Spring Boot 2.3.1, the maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3, JDK 11 and for testing JUnit4 with the okhttp3 mockwebserver 4.0.1. Do you have any idea what this problem could be caused by ?

Comment: You’ve got a mistake in your setup method; you’re declaring a WebClient local variable which is presumably shadowing the one at the class level.

Comment: Sorry was my fault. I copied an earlier version of the code <.<. Its know changed in my example. The webClient is actually visible for the whole Test Class and not local to the setup method.